# How to apply import range to a cell through appscript?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, importrange

I need to sync the page only when button is clicked (Apply formulas through appscript).
So my problem is there so many sheets linked.
Whenever my team people updated sheets, other sheets gets slow down because the sheets are linked.
So need whenever i click the button it syncs, get the updated data.

Answer (score 0):

the following script would insert the importrangeformula, and then unlink it by copying the data, and replacing the formula.

Essentially the steps are, when you run the script,

1) it inserts the importange formula

2) copy the data and paste it back again, removing the importrange formula.

```
function ImportOnDemand() {
  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var ss = app.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Test");// sheet where you want to place your importrange formula
  sheet.getDataRange().clearContent();
  sheet.getRange(1,1).setValue('=importrange("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/examplesheet/edit#gid=0","Master!A1:A100")')//replace original importrangeformula here, use ' to insert formula
  var rangeToCopy = sheet.getDataRange();
  rangeToCopy.copyTo(sheet.getRange(1,1),{formatOnly:true});
  rangeToCopy.copyTo(sheet.getRange(1,1),{contentsOnly:true}); //static the data so it is no longer connected
}
```